# REST API for Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm looking for a tool that will allow me to query my Redshift cluster via a REST API? I'm building some analytics UI and would rather not have to stand up a separate server in order to query my instance.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

You could use boto SDK to describe redshift clusters. (describe_clusters)
http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/redshift.html